# Calling validation event of ngNativeValidate on button click

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to call validation event of ngNativeValidate on button click. You can find stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5kuwk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

https://angular-v5kuwk.stackblitz.io/

In the stackblitz, "Test" button do not validate min and max value of input text number but submit button does.

How I can resolve this?

Comment: You Test button `(click)` is not calling a method.  Maybe you mean to call `(click)="testFormData1(formData1.valid)"`?

Comment: test button type should be submit `<button type="submit" (click)="testFormData1(formData1.dirty)">Test</button>`

Comment: It works by edit: `<button type="submit" (click)="testFormData1(formData1.valid, formData1.value)">Test</button>` and inside testFormData1 function checking the value of valid.